# Azure auto-scale and Docker Swarm

Tags: azure, autoscaling, docker-swarm

I'm trying to figure out how Azure auto-scale settings / VM Scale Set and might Docker Swarm work together.

Let's say I have three virtual machines all of which have Docker installed and are configured to be part of the same Swarm (1 manager and 2 workers).  In this Swarm there is a service running from a docker-compose.yml.

When the VM CPU gets to a certain percentage I would like for a new VM to be spun up which is added as a worker to the swarm and which runs the service.

Is this possible? I have tried the Azure Docker beta (actually now out of beta as of yesterday), this puts managers and workers into scale sets but there is not autoscaling configured.

Many thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an answer I got from Deep Debroy at Docker on the Docker Community Slack channel:

"the scale sets in Docker4Azure does not support Azure auto scaling at the moment. We will look at this for our next release. Today you can manually scale the vm scale set for workers up when you need more capacity as well as scale it down manually. The worker nodes will be added/removed respectively. However the scale sets can’t be configured to do it automatically today based on CPU consumption metrics."

Comment: Keep your fingers crossed. Some manual work will save us for now :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get automatic scaling of Docker Swarm based on CPU and RAM consumption using pre-packaged Jelastic template. The installation is automated and by default includes the needed triggers (they can be adjusted).

The details are in the article "[Docker Swarm Auto-Clustering and Scaling with PaaS Power Armor.](https://jelastic.com/blog/docker-swarm-auto-clustering-and-scaling-with-paas/)" And Jelastic PaaS can be run on Azure infrastructure if it is required, if it is not "must-have", you can choose any of their local providers that suits more.